# A simple algorithm to solve the MST Sensitivity Analysis problem in linear time when the MST is a path

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, computational-geometry, minimum-spanning-tree

**The problem.** Given an undirected, connected, edge-weighted graph $G=(V, E_G; w)$ and a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) (MST) $T=(V, E_T)$  of $G$, the *MST sensitivity analysis* problem asks to find, for each edge $f \in E_T$, the increase between the total weight $\sum_{e \in E_T} w(e)$ of $T$ and the total weight of a MST of $G-f$.

Let $n=|V|$ and $m=|E_G|$. [It is known](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/papers/sf-JGAA.pdf) that the above general problem can be solved in time $O(m \log \alpha(m, n))$, where $\alpha$ is the [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse). I am interested in a *restricted version* of the above problem in which $T$ is guaranteed to be a path.

The paper linked above shows a reduction between the general MST sensitivity analysis problem and the problem of computing a MST. One of the steps of the reduction involves solving the MST sensitivity analysis problem on an instance of the restricted problem. The author claims that this can be done in *linear time* and "this is an easy exercise".

Does anybody know or has a reference to a **simple** linear-time algorithm to perform the sensitivity analysis of a graph when its MST is a path?

**An involved solution on the RAM model.**
If we number the vertices of $G$ with the integers from $1$ to $n$, as they appear when traversing $T$ from one endpoint of the path to the other, then we only need to find, for each edge $(u,v) \in E_T$, an edge $(x,y) \in E_G \setminus E_T$ with $x \le u$ and $y \ge v$ such that $w(x,y)$ is minimized.
This can be equivalently reformulated as follows:
we are given $m$ horizontal segments whose endpoints have integer $x$-coordinates in $\{1, \dots, n\}$. We need to report, for each $x \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, the height of the highest (or lowest) segment intersecting the vertical line passing through $x$.

This is essentially the problem of computing the upper/lower envelope of a set of horizontal segments, which [can be solved in linear time](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01840436.pdf) *on the RAM model* provided that a list of the segments' endpoints in left-to-right order is known (this is the case our instances since the sorted endpoints of the segments are the endpoints of the non-tree edges as they appear in a traversal of the path).
Such an algorithm requires bit manipulations and I wouldn't consider coming up with it an *easy exercise*, so I doubt that this is what the author had in mind.